# How can you resolve Docker hostnames from the parent host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
docker-compose up
```

. . .

```
docker-compose ps

Name                               Command               State                         Ports                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                             
localdockerdbandredis_kafka2_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9093->9092/tcp, 9093/tcp                   
localdockerdbandredis_kafka3_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9094->9092/tcp, 9094/tcp                   
localdockerdbandredis_spacejam_mysql_1   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                             
localdockerdbandredis_spacejam_redis_1   docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                             
localdockerdbandredis_zookeeper_1        /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Is there a way to resolve the name `localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1` from the host. For example,

```
telnet localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1 9092
```

The developer who set up our environment has our code being able to connect to `localdockerdbandredis_spacejam_mysql_1` by name, but he is on vacation, and I am new to docker, so I cannot figure out how I can refer to Kafka by name.

My docker.compose-yml file looks like

```
version: '2'

services:

  spacejam_mysql:
    # image: mariadb:10.1.14
    # image: mysql:5.6
    image: iggcanada/mysql
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ????
      MYSQL_USER: ????
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ????
    networks:
      - madlands

  spacejam_redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - madlands

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    expose:
      - "2181"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - madlands

# http://wurstmeister.github.io/kafka-docker

  kafka1:
    build: .
    expose:
      - "9092"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - madlands

  kafka2:
    build: .
    expose:
      - "9093"
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localdockerdbandredis_kafka2_1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - madlands

  kafka3:
    build: .
    expose:
      - "9094"
    ports:
      - "9094:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localdockerdbandredis_kafka3_1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - madlands

# Create our named network of type bridge
networks:
  madlands:
    driver: bridge
```

Basically in our code I want to be able to configure kafkaBootstrapServers as

```
spacejam.kafka.bootstrap.servers = "localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1:9092,localdockerdbandredis_kafka2_1:9093,localdockerdbandredis_kafka3_1:9094"
```

the way our code uses

```
akka-persistence-sql-async.url = "jdbc:mysql://localdockerdbandredis_spacejam_mysql_1/spacejam_akka_persistence"
```

elsewhere.

I have been searching documentation on how to resolve names from Docker, but still have not found anything that seems to describe how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the result of `docker network inspect madlands`? Just curious to see if that has anything to do with the networking why it works for mysql and not kafka.

Answer (score 1):

From you docker-compose output you can see the port mappings

```
Name                               Command               State                         Ports                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                             
localdockerdbandredis_kafka2_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9093->9092/tcp, 9093/tcp                   
localdockerdbandredis_kafka3_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:9094->9092/tcp, 9094/tcp
```

So for you Kafka1, Kafka2, Kafka the ports mapped are 9092, 9093, 9094. Which means you can telnet to them on localhost and these port

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9092
```

On your machine will connect you to Kafka1. To connect to Kafka 2 you will use

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9093
```

The only way to refer to these by name is to make a host entry in your system and point that either to localhost or your machine IP (if host file not on your machine)

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_1 localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_2 localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_3
```

Now only problem you may face is when connecting to `localdockerdbandredis_kafka1_2` from code running on your machine (outside docker) as kafka works using advertised host name and on port 9092 but your machine will only provide access of Kafka 1 on 9092.

So make these three host entries, point them to local and see if everything works

Comment: `telnet 127.0.0.1 9092` does work, but I cannot embed that in my program. Also, the solution cannot include having to edit the /etc/hosts file. If you are saying I cannot do what I want to do, that is an acceptable answer, However, it seems someone has already figured this out, but he is on vacation for another two weeks. I was hoping that when Docker is running, it somehow exposes its internal DNS to the host it is running on.

Comment: Just to confirm, adding hostnames to /etc/hosts does work. I will have to talk to the rest of my team to see if this is an acceptable way to work. Thanks muchly for the hint Tarun.